Clicking Close button results in error popup from FreeSimpleGUI
I am using FreeSimpleGUI to create a to-go list interface. When I click on the "Exit" button it closes as normal, but when I click on the "Close" button it result in this popup, how do I resolve this please? This is my first time posting here, so I apologise for any formatting issues.
GUI
Error Message
import functions
import FreeSimpleGUI as sg
import time
import os

if not os.path.exists("todos.txt"):
    with open("todos.txt", "w") as file:
        pass

sg.theme("Black")

clock = sg.Text('', key='clock')
label = sg.Text("Type in a to-do")
input_box = sg.InputText(tooltip="Enter to-do", key="todo")
add_button = sg.Button("Add")
list_box = sg.Listbox(values=functions.get_todos(), key='todos',
                      enable_events=True, size=[45, 10])
edit_button = sg.Button("Edit")
complete_button = sg.Button("Complete")
exit_button = sg.Button("Exit")

window = sg.Window('My To-Do App',
                   layout=[[clock],
                           [label],
                           [input_box, add_button],
                           [list_box, edit_button, complete_button],
                           [exit_button]],
                   font=('Helvetica', 20))

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=500)
    window["clock"].update(value=time.strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"))
    match event:
        case "Add":
            todos = functions.get_todos()
            new_todo = values['todo'] + "\n"
            todos.append(new_todo)
            functions.write_todos(todos)
            window['todos'].update(values=todos)

        case "Edit":
            try:
                todo_to_edit = values['todos'][0]
                new_todo = values['todo'] + "\n"

                todos = functions.get_todos()
                index = todos.index(todo_to_edit)
                todos[index] = new_todo
                functions.write_todos(todos)
                window['todos'].update(values=todos)
            except IndexError:
                sg.popup("Please select an item first", font=("Helvetica", 20))

        case "Complete":
            try:
                todo_to_complete = values['todos'][0]
                todos = functions.get_todos()
                todos.remove(todo_to_complete)
                functions.write_todos(todos)
                window['todos'].update(values=todos)
                window['todo'].update(value='')
            except IndexError:
                sg.popup("Please select an item first", font=("Helvetica", 20))

        case "Exit":
            break
        case 'todos':
            window['todo'].update(value=values['todos'][0])
        case sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

window.close()


You are calling window["clock"].update() after the call to window.read() - even the very last call, the one that reports to you that the window was closed.  It's obviously too late at that point to update the displayed time!  Try moving that up one line, so that it's always called at a point where you window still exists.
